# bootstrap div cant keep the width on small screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have tried to create 3 inputs with this code

```
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6">
    <form>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-0.5 search-label">
          <label class="control-label">Search :</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" v-model="company_name" @keyup="userFilterGlobal" class="form-control" placeholder="Company">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" v-model="fullname" @keyup="userFilterGlobal" class="form-control" placeholder="Fullname">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" v-model="email" @keyup="userFilterGlobal" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

it works fine but with different resolutions, it gets break such as

[image]

it's right till that point. but the inputs again get huge when there is a smaller screen.

[image]

How can I keep it to the same pictures 1 size of inputs when the screen gets smaller than picture 1?

Code pen for testing https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oRYZBx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

`<div class="col-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">`

to your input field divs and adjust "2" according to your needed size based on screen size.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQozOR)

More info can be found on bootstrap grid system [page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#responsive-classes)

Answer (score 0):

The `col-sm` has it's `min-width` to 576px, it won't effect to screen width less than that

If you'd like to make the `col` always mini to 5, you can use `col-5` directly in Bootstrap 4 like this

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="col-5 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-form-label">Search :</label>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" v-model="company_name" @keyup="userFilterGlobal" class="form-control" placeholder="Company">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" v-model="fullname" @keyup="userFilterGlobal" class="form-control" placeholder="Fullname">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input type="text" v-model="email" @keyup="userFilterGlobal" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

And, you should not skip the [container](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#containers) and [row](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#how-it-works) levels of Bootstrap and use the `col` directly, you can either use `.container` or `.container-fluid` as you want

Or you might face padding, margin or float clean problem when your layout become complex

Comment: I've update my answer to demonstrate how should Bootstrap classes be structured, there are many ways to reach what you need. Like the Form Row of Bootstrap Form: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-row

Answer (score 0):

It's Basically depends on Responsiveness on Screen I share code please check this -

```
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
    <form>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-0.5 search-label">
          <label class="control-label">Search :</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
          <input type="text" v-model="company_name" @keyup="userFilterGlobal" class="form-control" placeholder="Company">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
          <input type="text" v-model="fullname" @keyup="userFilterGlobal" class="form-control" placeholder="Fullname">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
          <input type="text" v-model="email" @keyup="userFilterGlobal" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: This won't work, it stacks input fields on smaller screens. Not what OP is looking for.

Comment: Please tell me which screen size you see.??

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap grid system to manage them according to your screen size.
You can read more about it from below link, hope so you will find your solution.
[Follow the link for details](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)